# PHP - show pages as count from DB

Tags: php, database

i have some problems with pages..
I use this code(something its wrong)
Image - [this is what i have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2cOQ.jpg)
When i press for next page(31) show me „page not exists”

```
if(!isset($_REQUEST['page']) || empty($_REQUEST['page'])) {
    $_REQUEST['page'] = 1;
}
$page = ceil($_REQUEST['page']);

                $limit = 14;
                $start = $limit;
                $end = $page*$limit-($limit);
                $query = CSA::getInstance()->sqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as `players` FROM `played_time`;");
                if($query->num_rows > 0) {
                    $getlist = $query->fetch_assoc();
                }
                $pages = ceil($getlist['players']/$limit);
                $previous = ($page - 1 <= 0) ? "<li class='disabled'><a href='#'>&laquo; Prev</a></li>" : "<li><a href=\"./categories-".CSA::getInstance()->sqli->real_escape_string($_GET['id'])."-".($page-1)."\">&laquo; Prev</a></li>";
                $nextpage = ($page + 1 > $pages) ? "<li class='disabled'><a href='#'>Next &raquo;</a></li>" : "<li><a href=\"./categories-".CSA::getInstance()->sqli->real_escape_string($_GET['id'])."-".($page + 1)."\">Next &raquo;</a></li>";
                echo $previous;
                for($i=1;$i<=$pages;$i++) {
                    $href = ($page == $i) ? "<li><a href='#'>".$i."</a></li>" : "<li class='active'><a href=\"./categories-".CSA::getInstance()->sqli->real_escape_string($_GET['id'])."-".$i."\">".$i."</a></li>";
                    echo $href;
                }
                echo $nextpage;
                echo "</ul>
            </div>";
```

Comment: that `-($limit)` looks strange to me. also `$getlist` might not be defined. please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ...because as the question currently is presented, it is neither complete nor verifiable. the string `page not exists` does not appear anywhere in that snippet. for improved readability: `$db = CSA::getInstance()->sqli;`

Comment: thank you for your quick answer!
I found this tutorial - http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/basic-pagination
and now I have edited my code as follows

Answer (score 0):

```
        if(isset($_REQUEST['page']) || is_numeric($_GET['page'])) {
        $page = (int) $_GET['page'];
    }
    else $page = 1;

$range = 3;

                    $limit = 14;
                    $start = $limit;
                    $end = $page*$limit-($limit);
                    $query = CSA::getInstance()->sqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as `players` FROM `played_time`;");
                    if($query->num_rows > 0) {
                        $getlist = $query->fetch_assoc();
                    }
                    $pages = ceil($getlist['players']/$limit);
                    $previous = ($page - 1 <= 0) ? "<li class='disabled'><a href='#'>&laquo; Prev</a></li>" : "<li><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=".($page-1)."'>&laquo; Prev</a></li>";
                    $nextpage = ($page + 1 > $pages) ? "<li class='disabled'><a href='#'>Next &raquo;</a></li>" : "<li><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=".($page+1)."'>Next &raquo;</a></li>";
                    echo $previous;

// if current page is greater than total pages...
if ($page > $pages) {
   // set current page to last page
   $page = $pages;
} // end if
// if current page is less than first page...
if ($page < 1) {
   // set current page to first page
   $page = 1;
} // end if

for ($x = ($page - $range); $x < (($page + $range) + 1); $x++) {
   // if it's a valid page number...
   if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $pages)) {
      // if we're on current page...
      if ($x == $page) {
         // 'highlight' it but don't make a link
         echo "<li class='active'><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=$i'>$x</a></li>";
      // if not current page...
      } else {
         // make it a link
         echo "<li><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=$x'>$x</a></li>";
      } // end else
   } // end if 
} // end for
```